# Why doesn't https://username:password@example.com work?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

I have a website that I'm trying to log into.  It is one of the websites that has a popup asking for your username/password right when you hit it.

The problem is that doing `https://username:password@my.site.example/` doesn't work, the popup will still remain.

The code is paused on the `driver.get()` (unless I manually type in the username/password in the popup), so I am unable to use anything like Robots (which I don't like anyways)

Anyways, what would be possible causes for the above URL not to work, and what is the applicable fix?

(I'm using FirefoxDriver)

Comment: looks doGet , why would someone risk login details in doGet ?

Comment: We have a test account to use in our `driver.get()`, as is standard practice with selenium.

Comment: oh ok . lot more for me to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

It sometimes doesn't work that way.If you aren't very specific doing that way, you can use Java AWT robot to do it.You can use driver.switchtoAlert() to switch to the pop-up and enter the username.The rest is handled by Robot.

See [here](https://github.com/Madusudanan/Selenium/blob/master/WindowsAuthHandler.java) for an example.If you are having problems switching to the window,you can use just the username and password entry.As of the updated version of chrome, the pop up box is no more a window and it comes up in a different way.But the idea works somewhat.

This is generally a tough situation and is beyond the scope of selenium to handle this and we have no other way other than turn to Robot and it turns out to be flaky.

If you are not satisfied with Java AWT and it does not work out well you can try out a third party library such as [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/),although I am not aware of the specifics of the implementation using that framework,I have heard that it is somewhat more stabler than Robot.

Edit : The code that I posted seems to work only with Internet Explorer(IEDriverServer) and does not work with Firefox or Chrome.We have to use AutoIT for other browsers.

Comment: As I said in the problem...the code is stuck on the `driver.get()`.  Using Robot or any other java code won't work (unless its some kind of setup that happens before I call the `driver.get()`)

Comment: Then I am afraid you have to resort to Auto IT.I will try it on my end and get back.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilized [browsermob proxy](http://bmp.lightbody.net/) with remote web driver.